# Serve file from server where file exists using AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, wowza, amazon-route53

I'm building a globally distributed streaming platform built with Wowza server. Reading this article on 
[How could I determine which AWS location is best for serving customers from a particular region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339990/how-could-i-determine-which-aws-location-is-best-for-serving-customers-from-a-pa) I'd like to use this method to pick the ingest server based on the geolocation or lowest latency.

On the other site our CDN needs to pull from the server that is being streamed to. Is there a way for the Route53 to select the server that doesn't return 404 for the requested content?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, yes, using Route53 health checks. That way, R53 can determine the appropriate endpoint that is "healthy" and serving up your content. I'm not sure what time gap would be involved though -- probably 30-90 seconds at least to detect an unhealthy endpoint and switch over.