# How to map city name to AWS region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, geolocation, region

In my application users just enter their address details like city, state, country, etc. Using this information and some other details, application is supposed to create cluster in the region which is nearer to the user.

I am not able to figure out how to map city, state, country to AWS specific region. Is  there any way to  map these address details with AWS region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9861749/473467) here on SO mentions a solution by TurnKey Linux.

You should check [Finding the closest data center using GeoIP and indexing](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/geoip-amazon-regions). It seems more like a proof-of-concept to me but it might point you in the right direction.